# Send multiple requests using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I am very new to using RxJava with Retrofit in Android. I have successfully written the API calls and developed the interface too. Now, I want to write my code in a way that I can send two requests: second request depending upon the values of first request. Can someone guide me if this is possible? If so then how? Any code snippet will really be helpful.

For example: following are two requests:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(fcService.getStationList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // "work" on io thread
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // "listen" on UIThread
                .subscribe(this::handleResults, this::handleError)
        );


mCompositeDisposable.add(fcService.getStationSensor("12345678")
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // "work" on io thread
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // "listen" on UIThread
                    .subscribe(this::handleResults, this::handleError)
            );
```

Second request is possible with the value from the first request's response. Is it possible to merge these two requests in a way that I write code only once for them?

Comment: We'd need to see the code for `handleResults` etc, and also we'd need to know what exactly you want to do. Do you want to just `getStationSensor()` for the first item in `getStationList()`? Do you want to `getStationSensor()` for every item? Only for certain items that meet some criteria? etc

Comment: @BenP. There are two scenarios: (1) Yes, you got it right. I want to  getStationSensor() for the first item in getStationList(). (2) When user changes the station from the station's list, I want to getStationSensor() on the change of the station. Any solution which can handle both? or at least the first one? handleResults just parses the List<Stations> to extract their names and populates the Dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

With the flatMap operator you can check the response of the first call and choose the next action to follow, in this way you build a new Observable that you can subscribe to (The next "code" is kotlin style):

```
Single<StationSensor> newSingle = 
fcService.getStationList().flatMap{ stationList ->
    when(stationList){
        "OK_value" -> fcService.getStationSensor(stationList)
        else -> Single.error(RuntimeException("Error response"))
    }
}
```